# What context should be used for `GATracker` in a Flash package?

Tags: flash, google-analytics, flash-cs4

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;    

    import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker; 
    import com.google.analytics.GATracker; 



    public class DetailView extends MovieClip {

        var tracker:AnalyticsTracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-BLABLA", "AS3", true );
```

I get this:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

This totally makes sense, because `this` reference a `type Class` object. But - if I can't pass a `type Class`, what should I pass?

The documentation is [here](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/) but I can't find any reference to what I should pass as the first argument to the constructor method.

**Edit #1**: Sounds like I need to pass a `displayObject`, http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/analytics/GATracker.as?r=398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because you use the `this` keyword before the DetailView is created.

You now use the `this` keyword in a context where class variables are declared (not inside any function). You should probably do it in a constructor (or possibly in a handler function for the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event).

Also, are you sure you want to declare `tracker` as a `AnalyticksTracker` and not a `GATracker`? Normally, you use the same type for the variable that stores the instance that you create using the `new` keyword (not always, but normally).

So you could try something like this:

```
public class DetailView extends MovieClip {

   private var tracker:GATracker;

   public function DetailView() {
      // Since this is the constructor, the this keyword will refer to the DetailView instance being created
      tracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-BLABLA", "AS3", true );
   }

}
```

Comment: Also, regarding passing in a DisplayObject, your DetailView is a DisplayObject, since MovieClip is a DisplayObject.

Comment: Actually, I think the code stops working after the `new GATracker` constructor - I have a `console.log call from ExternalInterface` before `new` and it logs, but the one after doesn't. Also, the GA documentation used `AnalyticsTracker` instead of `GATracker` in the snippet: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingSetupFlash.html#useAnalyticsLibrary